# Managing JupyterLab extensions with different Conda environments

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab, code-formatting

I've been trying to install a code formatter into Jupyter lab. I'm unsure how to manage such extensions with multiple conda environments.

I have JupyterLab installed on my base conda environment and then add environment kernels to Jupyter with the following commands:

```
conda install -c anaconda ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=test --display-name "test”
```

I've installed [JupyterLab code formatter](https://github.com/ryantam626/jupyterlab_code_formatter) on the base environment with

```
conda install jupyterlab-code-formatter
```

and then installed a few formatters as suggested in the [documentation](https://jupyterlab-code-formatter.readthedocs.io/installation.html) (again on the base environment):

```
pip install black
pip install yapf
pip install isort
pip install autopep8
```

The formatters do work successfully regardless of which kernel (base or otherwise) is running on a notebook, but I am just unsure if some of these steps should have (or even could have) been done outside of the base conda environment.